# Pronunciation of "cul"

Tags: prononciation

Stupid question may be but I've just realized that "cul" is pronounced [ku]; that is the final l is not pronounced. Is there is a reason for doing so? As far as I know -l is usually pronounced as in, for instance,

> personnel, essentiel, général, principal

and

> miel, mal, sel

There are of course words like outil and gentil where -l is not pronounced but my question is limited here to the word "cul".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The l at the end is explained [here](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/culus#la), (Wiktionnaire). This word has its root in Indo-European "*(s)keu*" (« couvrir ») qui donne cutis (« peau »), cunnus (« con »), obscurus (« couvert, obscur »), cucullus (« cape »).*" and the latin "*culus*" (fesses).

Apparently, there is no acknowledged definite reason for not pronouncing this l. The [etymology in the TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cul) (repeated below for convenience) says that often the l was not written; there is nothing about the l having been suppressed because it was not pronounced nor vice-versa.

> Prononc. et Orth. : [ky]. l final est imprononcé dans le simple comme dans les dér. du type : cul-blanc, gratte-cul, cul-de-jatte, etc. Le mot est admis ds Ac. 1694-1932; les éd. de 1694 et 1718 soulignent que, souvent, on n'écrit pas l; à comparer avec les éd. de 1762-1878 qui ajoutent qu'on supprime parfois l dans l'écriture; l'éd. de 1740 note qu'il disparaît dans les expr. cu-bas, cu-levé. Mais la majorité des dict., y compris Ac. à part l'éd. de 1740, orthographient cul-levé. Littré et DG enregistrent cu en tant que var. moins usitée de cul. Les mots composés à partir de cul.

Some precisions can be found, those being of a general phonetic sort and to be found in the article "[*Les consonnes finales*](https://virga.org/cvf/consfina.php); these deductions are based on "*Le Nouveau Dictionnaire de Rimes*", (1648,  Fremont d’Ablancourt).

> Comme le montre le relevé des annotations concernant les consonnes finales (tableau 3), ce dictionnaire mentionne un certain nombre de mots dont la consonne finale ne se prononce pas. Outre des cas déjà bien connus, notamment depuis La Noue, comme plom(b), cler(c), ble(d), pie(d), respec(t), on en trouve certains que le même La Noue n’aurait probablement pas acceptés : nid, tournois, cul mais on reste jusqu’ici dans les mots isolés, et dans la confrontation d’un usage particulier (celui [dictionnaire] de La Noue) avec un autre usage particulier (celui de Fremont). Plus significative, l’affirmation que tous les mots ou presque d’une catégorie, comme ceux en « -il dont l’l mouille » ou en -oir se prononcent sans leur consonne finale. Est-ce à dire qu’ils s’en passent aussi pour rimer ? On sait par contre que les mots en -erf (serf excepté) « peuuent rimer auec ceux en R rude » et qu’il en est de même pour -ing, -oing, -ourg et -in, -oin, -our puisque les uns renvoient aux autres. Il en va de même de -amp qui renvoie à -ant.

Comment: Thank you very much.